# When using mysygit (GitGui), is there a log of the git bash commands executed?

Tags: git, msysgit, git-gui

I am new to using git and use msysgit with GitGui exclusively because I only need to do basic pulls and pushes.

When I need help, all of the answers I find are given with git bash which does not help me with GitGui.

In order to be able to understand what I am doing with GutGui in terms of git bash commands, I was wondering if GitGui keeps a log of the git bash commands executed for the actions from GitGui actions?

Once I have this I can better understand what I am doing in GitGui as git bash commands and then make better use of GitGui.

Comment: Of interest: [DebuggingGitkOrGitGui](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/DebuggingGitkOrGitGui)

Comment: Of interest: [Git Internals - Environment Variables](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
You can start git-gui with `--trace` flag. On Windows it opens two windows: git-gui and tcl console which also logs executed commands by git-gui [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18474917/2351523) [[proj. wiki]](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/DebuggingGitkOrGitGui#Git_Gui_specific).
You can also open console during running git-gui with `CTRL` + `F2`, and turn on logging with: `set _trace 1`.

But keep in mind that those commands are "low-level" and shouldn't be used during normal git usage.

Comment: I know it's old question but I stumbled upon it, and I like completeness :)

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out and appreciate the answer even if it took some years before appearing. I don't view StackOverflow as a place where people come to get a quick answer, but a place as a repository of useful information related to programming. I am so tired of seeing the same questions re-asked again and again when just some searching and reading will give you the answer. I also tend to verify an answer before accepting it so it may take a few days, but if you check if the answer is valid or reasonable I do give the accept vote.

Comment: I did take a cursory look at this but have not had time to fully explore; my fault not yours. I don't think this was exactly what I wanted, but it appears to be what I asked, thus the accept vote. If I do find it is not what I wanted hopefully I will have learned enough to ask another more specific question. Thanks.