# Can I see what commands git-gui is executing?

Tags: git, git-gui

Is there a way to see what commands [git-gui](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gui.html) is executing? Either in some status bar, or log perhaps? That would be really useful for learning the command line better.

Comment: Can we assume you mean [this one](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gui.html) called "git-gui"? Otherwise you'll have to specify, because there are [quite a few](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) GUIs for Git out there.

Comment: yes, thanks, I'll edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: It might be possible to run `exec git gui &` under tkcon and use *send* to do some introspection, but I've never tried it.

Comment: @CodeGnome git-gui explicitly disables the Tk send functionality. The original author deemed it a security problem (although it is not in fact).

Comment: @patthoyts You appear to be correct; I tried it and found the functionality disabled. I'd be very interested if you have a URL or other source for this design decision.

Comment: @CodeGnome there is a comment attached to the line in the code where this is disabled. Seems pretty clear why it was done from that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. git-gui accepts a `--trace` option which will make it print each git command it executes on stderr. If you are running on Windows where there is no stderr, then it also shows the Tk console and this output is visible there. On Windows you can also show the console with Ctrl-F2 even without the --trace option if you want to do some debugging on the running application. On other systems, stderr will appear in the console window you launched the application from. If you used a desktop icon or shortcut, you might want to start a terminal window and start it manually to see the output (unix or macos).

Comment: This seems to work, but where is this documented? It's not in git-gui(1).

Comment: @patthoyts Wow, that's pretty some crazy secret knowledge. Seems that git-gui uses git-core commands such as "git-update-index.exe", "git-diff-index.exe", "git-check-attr.exe" rather the usual/typical command line. I don't suppose there's a way get those, huh? Well, this is still kind of useful.

Comment: This prevent some commands from being used. For example, the "revert" command (Ctrl + J) doesn't seem to work (tested on Ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 2):

I created a desktop shortcut to point to the version control directory I work with most of the time:

> "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git-gui.exe" "--working-dir" "C:\my\version\control\directory" "--trace"